# Eclipse STS console fails to display some UTF-8 chars

Tags: eclipse, utf-8, sts, euro

I am using Spring Tool Suite v4.13.1, a customisation of Eclipse 3.18.

I have the following code:

```
NumberFormat fChina = NumberFormat.getCurrencyInstance(Locale.SIMPLIFIED_CHINESE);
NumberFormat fFrance = NumberFormat.getCurrencyInstance(Locale.FRENCH);
System.out.println("French: " + fFrance.format(123456.78));
System.out.println("China:  " + fChina.format(123456.78));
```

And the output I see on the console is:

French: 123 456,78 ¤
China:  ¥123,456.78

So, the Chinese currency character appears correctly but the € symbol does not.

In trying to solve this I have included UTF-8 encoding in the run configuration like so:

```
java -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8 -classpath /home/.../target com.example.Currencies
```

I have also changed the font used by the Terminal to FreeMono Regular but that did not make any difference.

I have read many postings related to UTF-8 but given that I can see the correct Chinese currency char, I think that might not be the right path.  Yet, I am at a loss as to why this widely used character would not display correctly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

¤ is Unicode U+00A4 - Currency Symbol.

The locale for France should be `Locale.FRANCE`, not `Locale.FRENCH`.

`Locale.FRENCH` covers anywhere that speaks French so the generic currency symbol is used. `Locale.FRANCE` will give you the Euro.

Comment: Thank you! That indeed did the trick.  The "SIMPLIFIED_CHINESE" instead of "CHINA" is what sent me off course...